# How to get the average duration of a process in Camunda?

Tags: javascript, rest, reporting, business-process-management, camunda

How to get the average duration of a process in Camunda through the REST api ?

Should I get all the instances process and calculate myself the average with '/history/process-instance' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no average method in the HistoryService API. You could do as suggested: find all historic instances and calculate the average of "durationInMillis"

or (if you have access to the server) you could write your own simple REST service based on a [custom query](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/real-life/how-to/#process-engine-custom-queries) and let the DB do the calculation for you.

Keep in mind that when reporting processes with user tasks, the mere start/end dates do not tell you anything about the actual work it took (consider a process started friday afternoon ... it will already have taken up 60h before the first user has a look at it. Its tricky to build a simple average over this process and the one started monday morning, which may be completed before noon).

Comment: > find all historic instances and calculate the average of "durationInMillis"

That may be a performance problem if you have many instances